# PowerBI replace blank values in grouped column relationship

Tags: powerbi

I have 2 tables, with one-to-many relationships

[image]

So usage_json.Username is matched with Personal Hierarchy.lower_user_name, in order to get details from Personal Hierarchy table.

So I have a visualization with the following grouping

[image]

The problem is that, for some records that do not match, the lvl_4_mgr_nm will appear as (Blank). So how do I replace this (Blank) values to "Others"?
Do I need to create another column, or is there any easy way to just change some settings to specify the default value?